# Get numerical property inside text property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this:

```
var myObj = {
    first: "str",
    second:{
    16: {option_one: "...", option_two: "..."},
    31: {option_one: "...", option_two: "..."},
    }
};
```

I can't change that code. But i need to get `16: {...}`. JS doesn't allow to do `myObj.second.16`. Can i do it with numeric name?

Comment: `myObj.second[16]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[` and `]` around `16`:

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "str",
    second:{
    16: {option_one: "...", option_two: "..."},
    31: {option_one: "...", option_two: "..."},
    }
};

console.log(myObj.second[16])
```